# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined using JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, leaflet

I'm trying to create a JS array of Leaflet markers, but it keeps telling me that the property '0' of the Markers[] array is undefined, i think it's a problem derivated from transfering the PHP variable $data to JS var a[] via json_encode, but i'm not sure about that.

I'm working on Altervista, i tried to solve the problem in every way possible.

```php
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM ritrovamento");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($sql)) 
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

```
var a = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;  
var Markers = [];
var Popups = [];
var j = 0;
var i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < a.length; i = i + 3) {
    Markers[i] = L.marker([a[j][0], a[j][1]], {icon: shovelIcon});
    Markers[i + 1] = L.marker([a[j][0], a[j][1]], {icon: diggingIcon});
    Markers[i + 2] = L.marker([a[j][0], a[j][1]], {icon: clickedIcon});
    Markers[i].addTo(mymap);   
    j++; 
}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (this error comes where i'm trying to put data into Markers[i]).

console.log(a) give me:

```
[Array(5)]
0: Array(5)
0: "45.255091"
1: "8.514025"
2: "/images/bo.gif"
3: "wdqd"
4: "wd"
```

and console.log(Markers[1]) gives me:

```
e {options: {…}, _latlng: M, _initHooksCalled: true}
options:
icon: e
options: {iconUrl: "images/digging.gif", iconSize: Array(2), iconAnchor: Array(2), popupAnchor: Array(2)}
_initHooksCalled: true
__proto__: v
__proto__: Object
_initHooksCalled: true
_latlng: M
lat: 45.255091
lng: 8.514025
__proto__: Object
__proto__: e
```

Same for Markers[0] and Markers[2].

Comment: What does the object really look like? A sample bit of it would help you get answers.

Comment: What is `i + 3` supposed to do in the `for` loop? Shouldn't that be `i = i + 3`?

Comment: I don't understand that loop. `i` is the index into `Markers`, not the index into `a`, so why are you comparing it to `a.length`?

Comment: `j` is the index into `a`, so you should compare that with `a.length`.

Comment: Corrected the increment in the for loop, nothing changed since there's only one element in the array.

Comment: The for loop serves to build up the Markers array since i must make three markers with three different icons to put in the map at different times, the J just increment by 1 at the end of for loop because it takes every row of the sql query for every cycle. a[j][0] and a[j][1] simply means take the lat value and the lng value of the first row got by  $sql query.

Comment: But anyway, if i put a[0][0] it gives me the same error. Seems like it the value does not have a some kind of property

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop since you're not incrementing `i`. On the second iteration you get an error because there's no `j[1]`.

The `for` loop needs to increment both variables, and it should test `j` since it's the index into the array you're reading.

```
for (i = 0, j = 0; j < a.length; j++, i += 3) {
    Markers[i] = L.marker([a[j][0], a[j][1]], {icon: shovelIcon});
    Markers[i + 1] = L.marker([a[j][0], a[j][1]], {icon: diggingIcon});
    Markers[i + 2] = L.marker([a[j][0], a[j][1]], {icon: clickedIcon});
    Markers[i].addTo(mymap);   
}
```

Here's full code. I tweaked the contents of the `Markers` array because I don't have `L.marker()` function, but it still accesses the `a` array the same way.

```js
var a = [
  ["45.255091", "8.514025", "/images/bo.gif", "wdgd", "wd"]
];

var Markers = [];
var j, i;
var mymap = [];

for (i = 0, j = 0; j < a.length; j++, i += 3) {
    Markers[i] = [[a[j][0], a[j][1]], {icon: "shovelIcon"}];
    Markers[i + 1] = [[a[j][0], a[j][1]], {icon: "diggingIcon"}];
    Markers[i + 2] = [[a[j][0], a[j][1]], {icon: "clickedIcon"}];
    mymap.push(Markers[i]);  
}

console.log(Markers);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200679/discussion-on-answer-by-barmar-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-0-of-u).